# how to get a random number with Haste

Tags: haskell, haste

I write a simple Haskell program using Haste ( https://www.haste-lang.org/ ). I need to get a random number from range 1-100. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`randomRIO (1,100) :: IO Int` would generate such a random number.

Note that since this is not a pure value, it can only be used inside the IO monad.

See the [`System.Random`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html) documentation for more information.